# Speeding up a differential equation system with nested modulo periodic events

Tags: difference-equations

I have the following differential equation system with periodic Events :

```
tg1 = 3; ts1 = 1; td1 = 1; nlagdil = 1/5; nlagtreat = 1/2;
s[nr_, nm_] := 
  First[ Evaluate[
    NDSolve[{n'[t] == nmu[t]*n[t], n[0] == 1, nmu[0] == 0, 
      timedil[0] == 0, timetreat[0] == tg1,
      WhenEvent[Mod[Mod[t, tg1 + ts1], td1] == 0, {n[t] -> n[t]/10^6, nmu[t] -> 0, timedil[t] -> t}], 
      WhenEvent[t - timedil[t] == nlagdil, {nmu[t] -> nr}], 
      WhenEvent[Mod[Mod[t, tg1 + ts1], tg1] == 0, {n[t] -> n[t], nmu[t] -> nm, timetreat[t] -> t}], 
      WhenEvent[t - timetreat[t] == ts1, {n[t] -> n[t]/100, nmu[t] -> 0}],
      WhenEvent[t - timetreat[t] == (ts1 + nlagtreat), {nmu[t] -> nr}] 
      },
     {n, nmu, timedil, timetreat}, {t, 0, 20}, 
     DiscreteVariables -> {nmu[t] \[Element] {0, nr, nm}, timedil[t], 
       timetreat[t]}, StartingStepSize -> 1/100, 
     Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", AccuracyGoal -> 100, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 100, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
     MaxStepFraction -> Infinity]]];
soln = s[10, -20];
LogPlot[Evaluate[{n[t]} /. soln], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Time", "n"}, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Classic", "LargeLabels"}]
```

[image]

(Well my actual system is larger, but this can serve as an example)

Problem is that I can only get Mathematica to detect the events with AccuracyGoal -> 100 and WorkingPrecision -> 100 which makes it really slow to solve. Does anybody have any thoughts how I could speed this up? Any other options or settings that would work for this?

EDIT: the answer below points out that the problem has to do with the nested `Mod[]` conditions. The solution below, unfortunately doesn't work since the proposed real valued function `doubleMod[t_,a_,b_]` is not fully equivalent to `Mod[Mod[t,a],b]` e.g. `Mod[Mod[1, tg1 + ts1], tg1] == 0` gives `False`, whereas `doubleMod[1, tg1 + ts1, tg1]` gives `{False,False}`. As an alternative way to get rid of the nested `Mod[]` I tried

```
s[nr_, nm_] := 
  First@NDSolve[{n'[t] == nmu[t]*n[t], n[0] == 1, nmu[0] == 0, 
     timedil[0] == 0, timetreat[0] == tg1, timestartround[0] == 0,
     WhenEvent[
      Mod[t, tg1 + ts1] == 
       0, {timestartround[t] -> Rationalize[t, 0.01]}],
     WhenEvent[
      Mod[t - timestartround[t], td1] == 0, {n[t] -> n[t]/10^6, 
       nmu[t] -> 0, timedil[t] -> t}],
     WhenEvent[t - timedil[t] == nlagdil, {nmu[t] -> nr}, 
      "Priority" -> 3],
     WhenEvent[
      Mod[t - timestartround[t], tg1] == 0, {n[t] -> n[t], 
       nmu[t] -> nm, timetreat[t] -> t}],
     WhenEvent[
      t - timetreat[t] == ts1, {n[t] -> n[t]/100, nmu[t] -> 0}],
     WhenEvent[t - timetreat[t] == (ts1 + nlagtreat), {nmu[t] -> nr}]},
    {n, nmu, timestartround, timedil, timetreat}, {t, 0, 20},
    DiscreteVariables -> {nmu[t], timestartround[t], timedil[t], 
      timetreat[t]}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    StartingStepSize -> 1/100, AccuracyGoal -> 70, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
    MaxStepFraction -> Infinity];
AbsoluteTiming[soln = s[10, -20];]
LogPlot[Evaluate[{n[t]} /. soln], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Time", "n"}, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Classic", "LargeLabels"}]
```

But this still requires the use of method `StiffnessSwitching`, and requires high accuracy and working precision, so is also really slow. Does anybody have any other thoughts about how to fix this? Basically I have several growth cycles (nr=tg1/td1) followed by an antibiotic treatment cycle of length ts1, which are then further iterated. Other possibility perhaps could be to recursively iterate this system, but I was wondering how to do this (ie how to patch together the different sections of the differential equation) and still obtain the same plot as shown above? (Obviously my real system is much more complicated, but I am mainly testing the events here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions that are giving you trouble are the nested `Mod`s, like this one:

```
Mod[Mod[t, tg1 + ts1], td1] == 0
```

The [documentation for `WhenEvent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) says:

> - `WhenEvent` typically finds a function `f` of the solution variables such that the roots of `f` occur where the event becomes `True`...
> - In the case that a root function cannot be determined, the bracketing interval is found using bisection.

However, the `Mod` functions never actually pass through zero, so the numerical algorithm has trouble finding their locations: since it doesn't see the sign of the function change, it thinks that it couldn't have passed through zero and never attempts bisection.  In fact, the first `WhenEvent` should be occurring every `1` time unit (its condition is `Mod[Mod[t,4],1]`, equivalent to `Mod[t,1]`) but clearly is being skipped in your plot.

Fortunately, there is a solution.  The documentation list a special type of event condition:

> `Mod[t, Δt] == 0`: sample at regular intervals `Δt` in the time variable `t`.

In this case, we can split the nested `Mod`s apart using a helper function:

```
doubleMod[t_, a_, b_] /; Mod[a, b] == 0 := Mod[t, b] == 0
doubleMod[t_, a_, b_] := 
 Table[Mod[t - (i - 1) b, a] == 0, {i, Ceiling[a/b]}]
```

Example usage:

```
Mod[Mod[t, tg1 + ts1], td1] == 0
doubleMod[t, tg1 + ts1, td1]
(* Mod[Mod[t, 4], 1] == 0 *)
(* Mod[t, 1] == 0 *)

Mod[Mod[t, tg1 + ts1], tg1] == 0
doubleMod[t, tg1 + ts1, tg1]
(* Mod[Mod[t, 4], 3] == 0 *)
(* {Mod[t, 4] == 0, Mod[-3 + t, 4] == 0} *)
```

Your original code takes around 1.2 seconds on my computer, but when revised using the `doubleMod` helper:

```
s[nr_, nm_] := 
  First@NDSolve[{n'[t] == nmu[t]*n[t], n[0] == 1, nmu[0] == 0, 
     timedil[0] == 0, timetreat[0] == tg1, 
     WhenEvent[
      Evaluate@doubleMod[t, tg1 + ts1, td1], {n[t] -> n[t]/10^6, 
       nmu[t] -> 0, timedil[t] -> t}], 
     WhenEvent[t - timedil[t] == nlagdil, {nmu[t] -> nr}], 
     WhenEvent[
      Evaluate@doubleMod[t, tg1 + ts1, tg1], {n[t] -> n[t], 
       nmu[t] -> nm, timetreat[t] -> t}], 
     WhenEvent[
      t - timetreat[t] == ts1, {n[t] -> n[t]/100, nmu[t] -> 0}], 
     WhenEvent[
      t - timetreat[t] == (ts1 + nlagtreat), {nmu[t] -> nr}]}, {n, 
     nmu, timedil, timetreat}, {t, 0, 20}, 
    DiscreteVariables -> {nmu[t], timedil[t], timetreat[t]}];
AbsoluteTiming[soln = s[10, -20];]
```

[image]

It takes only 0.016 seconds (and hits all the events).  No extra options are needed.  (I usually find that if I need to pass lots of extra options to `NDSolve` then I'm doing something wrong.)

Note that in this case, the events do not depend on `n[t]` and `n` obeys a trivial exponential model.  It may be even faster to remove `n` from `NDSolve`, compile a list of events that set `n` and `nmu`, and compute `n` from the breakpoints afterward.  Removing `n`, however, leaves only `DiscreteVariables` remaining so you don't even really need `NDSolve` for this problem.  If you need speed, it will be much faster to roll your own algorithm: at each step, compute when each event will occur next, step directly to the nearest event, increment your variables appropriately, then repeat.

### Update

Based on our discussion, I've come up with a method of programmatically generating the `WhenEvent`s to avoid the need for the nested `Mod`s in the first place (which weren't behaving like you expected anyway).  First we set up the definitions of your tests:

The tests repeat in the pattern defined by `testSchedule`, which is a list of indexes in the following arrays.

```
testSchedule = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3};
```

Then we define the tests; for each test, dilution by `dilutionFactor` occurs immediately, then after `growthDelay` time units, the growth factor is set to `growthFactor` for `growthTime` time units before beginning the next test.

```
dilutionFactor = {1/10^6, 1, 1/100};
growthDelay = {0.2, 0.5, 0.5};
growthFactor = {10, -20, -20};
growthTime = {1, 1, 1};
(*sanity checks*)
Length[dilutionFactor] == Length[growthDelay] ==
  Length[growthFactor] == Length[growthTime]
And @@ Map[IntegerQ[#] && 1 <= # <= Length[dilutionFactor] &, testSchedule]
And @@ Thread[growthDelay > 0]
And @@ Thread[growthTime > 0]
```

Now we can compute the event times:

```
With[{df = dilutionFactor[[testSchedule]],
  gd = growthDelay[[testSchedule]],
  gf = growthFactor[[testSchedule]],
  gt = growthTime[[testSchedule]]},
 tDilution = Most[Accumulate[gd] + Accumulate[gt]]~Prepend~0
    tGrowth = Accumulate[gd] + Most[Accumulate[gt]]~Prepend~0
      tRepeat = Total[gd] + Total[gt]
       events = Join @@ Table[{
        Evaluate /@ 
         WhenEvent[
          Mod[t, tRepeat] == tDilution[[i]], {n[t] -> n[t]*df[[i]], 
           nmu[t] -> 0}],
        Evaluate /@ 
         WhenEvent[
          Mod[t, tRepeat] == tGrowth[[i]], {nmu[t] -> gf[[i]]}]
        }, {i, Length[testSchedule]}]
 ]
```

Finally we solve the differential equation.

```
soln = NDSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] nmu[t], n[0] == 1, nmu[0] == 0}~Join~
   events, {n, nmu}, {t, 0, 20}, DiscreteVariables -> {nmu[t]}, 
  MaxStepSize -> (Min[growthDelay, growthTime]/10)]
LogPlot[Evaluate[{n[t]} /. soln], {t, 0, 2 tRepeat}, 
 PlotPoints -> 1000]
Plot[Evaluate[{nmu[t]} /. soln], {t, 0, 2 tRepeat}, 
 PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention, removing the restriction on the values of `nmu` sped the code up by 2x (from 40x faster to 75x faster).

Comment: Thanks millions for this! I notice there must still be a slight mistake though, as the graph, with identical parameters, is not exactly the same - in my example I have short delay nlagdil followed by exponential increase at rate nr and 10^6 fold dilution, repeated 3 times, followed by treatment and exponential decay at rate nm  and 100 fold dilution, followed by long delay nlagtreat and exponential growth at rate nlagdil, and then repeated. In your code, the mortality doesn't seem to go on for long enough and the long delay nlagtreat is missing. (Btw my actual eqn are a system of diff eqns)

Comment: So basically I have three main types of events here - I have regrowth after dilution (here at t=0, t=1, t=2, t=5, t=6 etc), treatments (here at t=3, t=7, etc) and regrowth after treatment and dilution (here at t=4 and t=8) and the lags are different after dilution vs after treatment. Would it help by any chance to put the time values of these events in a list first, and then checking if t is a member of any of these lists to check event locations?

Comment: The issue apparently is something with the `doubleMod` function - e.g. `Mod[Mod[1, tg1 + ts1], tg1] == 0` gives `False`, whereas `doubleMod[1, tg1 + ts1, tg1]` gives `{False,False}` - I tried changing the `doubleMod` function to `doubleMod[t_, a_, b_] /; Mod[a, b] == 0 := 
 Mod[t, b] == 
  0 
doubleMod[t_, a_, b_] := 
 Max[Boole[Table[Mod[t - (i - 1) b, a] == 0, {i, Ceiling[a/b]}]]] == 1` but no joy yet... Any thoughts?

Comment: I was thinking `doubleMod[t_, a_, b_] := 
 MemberQ[Table[Mod[t - (i - 1) b, a] == 0, {i, Ceiling[a/b]}], True]` should be able to fix things, but it doesn't - any thoughts why this event then doesn't get detected, because if you plot it the value of the condition over time it shows the right values? As in `ListPlot[Table[{t, Boole[doubleMod[t, tg1 + ts1, tg1]]}, {t, 0, 20, 
   1/10}]]` which is then identical to `ListPlot[Table[{t, Boole[Mod[Mod[t, tg1 + ts1], tg1] == 0]}, {t, 0, 
   20, 1/10}]]`

Comment: @Tom Why is `doubleMod[1, tg1 + ts1, tg1] == {False, False}` unexpected?  `doubleMod` gives a single condition of the form `Mod[t, _] == 0`, or breaks the `Mod`s into multiple conditions of the form `Mod[t + _, _] == 0`.  This is because `WhenEvent` expects either a function whose roots can be expressed by `Root`, a numerically tractable equation (which must change sign; `Mod` does not since it is always nonnegative), or something of the form `Mod[t + _, _] == 0`, which executes at regular intervals in `t`.  `doubleMod` can return a list, because `WhenEvent` will handle a list of conditions.

Comment: Your problem using `ListPlot` to check the results is that your functions using `MemberQ` and `Max`/`Boole` are only true at a finite set of points.  Since `t` can be any real number, the events represent in some sense an "infinitely thin" subset of `t`, meaning that `NDSolve` won't see them.  Try using `Plot` instead (like `Plot[Boole[Mod[Mod[t,tg1+ts1],tg1]==0],{t,0,20}]`); you'll see that it misses every event.  `NDSolve` can, however, recognize the non-nested `Mod` forms, and trigger those events appropriately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22397/discussion-between-2012rcampion-and-tom-wenseleers).

Comment: Thx so much - this works perfectly for me, and it's so much faster and reliable!